# Android assistant app action - Open "app_name" command does not work in other languages. Only works in English

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant, app-actions

I have been trying to integrate my application with google assistant. I was able to make it work in English language with following sample code - 
https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin 
However I couldn't find anything for Japanese language. And by reading native intents document I found that it only support few locale. 
But few apps like Spotify and Netflix can be opened using Japanese command like - 
オープン Spotify

Now I have looked into App Action Builder and checked their codelab guide. but I couldn't find any solid example on how to implement "Open aap_name" command.

If Android app action can be configured for different language or not. If yes How ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your first question.  The second one asking for a guide is [off topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and could get your question removed from the site (I suggest you edit it out).

Each App Actions BII supports a limited set of languages.  You can find out what is supported by consulting the documentation for that BII.  If you're asking about the "open app feature" BII, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature) states that only these languages are supported: en-US, en-GB, en-CA, en-IN, en-BE, en-SG, en-AU, es-ES, pt-BR

The behavior you're seeing for other apps opening with a voice command might not have anything to do with App Actions.  Assistant might just already recognize the name of the app as part of its own internal configuration.

If are working with App Actions and you find that it doesn't recognize the name of your app after you've performed a full integration, you should reach out to [Assistant support](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/support/) to explain that you need Assistant to recognize the name.

Comment: Hello @doug Thank you for your response. I think name of the app is being recognized but it works with English. When I try japanese it opens web page. What do you think ?